# Does review board support CCRC clearcase

Tags: clearcase, review-board, clearcase-remote-client

I have a CCRC instance(Version: 9.0.0 Build id: 9.0.1.04.00_2018C.D180725) and do not have the clearcase instance locally installed. Need a code review tool like review board. Read from different sources that review board supports clearcase, but not sure about CCRC. Does review board can be used for CCRC also?

Answer (score 1):

That [was mentioned in 2009](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reviewboard/a8DOj-lvslY), but [official documentation of reviewboard.org](https://www.reviewboard.org/integrations/clearcase/) does not include CCRC officially.

The [`rbt` CLI](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/rbtools/1.0/rbt/commands/post/#clearcase) still relies on `cleartool`, as you can see in [this 2017 ticket](https://hellosplat.com/s/beanbag/tickets/4547/)

```
rbt post --summary="Demo Test" --description="Demo" brtype:my_branch
...
>>> Running: cleartool lsview -full -properties -cview
```

So I don't see any native support for a CCRC usage.

Comment: This almost means that RB can not be used for CCRC. Is there any workaround for this or better go for other review tool?!

Comment: @Ravi Indeed, using RB with CCRC does not seem to be supported. CodeCollaborator/SmartBear seems to support CCRC (https://smartbear.com/blog/develop/updated-code-review-integration-clearcase-remote-c/)